# Image Sequence to Movie - How to Get Desired Frame Rate?

Tags: animation, frame-rate

I rendered 250 frames to png for an animation.
I opened these images as `Image Sequence` in QuickTime (10.5), and set the frame rate to 25 per second. This should give me a movie of 10 seconds.

I got a 10 second movie, **BUT** all 250 images play within the first 4 seconds, and the remaining 6 seconds are just a still frame of my 250th image!

When I enter other frame rates, like 60 / second, I get a 4 second movie, but all the movement is in the first 40%, then only a still frame.

***How can I create a movie from my 250 png images that actually plays at 25 fps?***

I don't have to stick to QT, it just seemed the easiest option. Anything on macOS would be ok. I had the same problem in Compressor though.

**EDIT** in response to Allen Simpson's easy-to-follow reply (thank you!)

Unfortunately same result as described above.

Sequence of 250 images:
[image: files]

start-frame, end-frame, 25 fps:
[image: settings]

Result: a 10s movie clip with all the movement in the first 4 seconds and a still frame for 6 seconds... Ouch! Can't get my head around this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for sure but the first thing I'd do is just render it out as an mp4 from Blender.

Here's a complete breakdown of the steps:

When you first open Blender hit the Video Editing preset.

[image]

Go to Add -> Image/Sequence.

[image]

Go to the folder containing your images and sort them by name so that they are in order going down the folder.  Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and add them to the timeline.

[image]

You should see the timeline something like this, now, and be able to play back your sequence with the controls at the bottom.

Note:  Playback will stutter because Blender does not prefetch the frames by default.  If you play it through a couple of times everything will be loaded in RAM, provided you do not run low, and it will play normally.

[image]

Now head over to the top right panel and make sure your resolution, frame start and end, and frame rate are what they should be.

[image]

Finally, scroll down to the Output section.  Pick a directory and change the file format to ffmpeg (or your choice).

And set the container and codec you want to use.

[image]